# Unable to reach ASP.NET MVC Web Api endpoint

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC app. I am trying to create a basic API. I created my first Web API controller by right-clicking on Controllers, Add -> Controller... then choosing "Web API 2 Controller - Empty". In the controller code, I have the following:

```
namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    public class MyApiController : ApiController
    {
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            var results = new[]
            {
                new { ResultId = 1, ResultName = "Bill" },
                new { ResultId = 2, ResultName = "Ted" }
            };
            return Ok(results);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the app, I enter `http://localhost:61549/api/myApi` in the browser's address bar. Unfortunately, I get a 404. I'm just trying to create an API endpoint that returns a hard-coded set of JSON objects. I need this to test some client-side JavaScript. What am I doing wrong?

Here are how my routes are registered:
**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
  config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
  );
}
```

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
}
```

Comment: I think you can just return IEnumerable and then return the anonymous objects.

Comment: @ThomasKoelle an IEnumerable of what? I thought IEnumerable required a type. Maybe I am misunderstanding something. However, I didn't think you could say IEnumerable<var>

Comment: your api end point is actually `/api/myapi/get` - if you want to use `/api/myapi` then you need an `Index()` action

Comment: also, throw an `[HttpGet]` above your method, for good measure

Comment: I did mean IEnumerable, without generics. Client has to do the proxy class anyway, or in case of ajax call get it from JSON using the names ResultId and ResultName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have the WebApiConfig registration being called, possibly in the Global.asax Application_Start() method. Something like:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not add method name at the end of call. Try this one:

```
http://localhost:61549/api/myapi/get
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
        public class MyApiController : ApiController
        {
            public IHttpActionResult Get()
            {
                var results = new List<ResultModel>
                {
                    new ResultModel() {ResultId = 1, ResultName = "Bill"},
                    new ResultModel() {ResultId = 2, ResultName = "Ted"}
                };
                return Ok(results);
            }

        }

        public class ResultModel
        {
            public int  ResultId { get; set; }
            public string ResultName { get; set; }
        }
}


Api: http://localhost:61549/api/MyApi/get
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. I'm still getting a 404. I've updated the post and included my route configuration. I noticed that the Register method in my WebApiConfig.cs is not getting called. Should it? If so, how do I get it to be called?